# knex migration fail, but doesnt revert changes

Tags: mysql, npm, knex.js

I want to use knex in my ts project. 
migration looks like this:

```
        export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<any> {
            return knex.schema.createTable('first_table', (t) => {
            t.integer('first_table_id').primary();
                 }).createTable('second_table', (t) => {
            t.integer('id');
            // simulation sql error, duplicate in this case.
            t.integer('id').
     })
}
```

Migration already fail. I wait transaction rollback for all changes but i have successfully created first_table. I do not understand something or Knex behaves incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

When mysql does DDL queries it does implicit commit. So after each query that creates a table transaction is committed automatically.

There is no really easy way around it except for taking DB dump before running migration and restoring it if the migration fails.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

For example with mysql if you do following:

```
* start transaction
* create table 1
* rollback
```

Table 1 will still be created and nothing was rolled back, because internally mysql does actually:

```
* start transaction
* create table 1
* implicit commit
* implicit start transaction for rollback query 
* rollback of automatically started empty transaction
```

Comment: We can rollback each transaction in Error case, if we talk about native mysql. But my question about knex. Knex - query builder, and knex have abstraction "transactions". 

By default, each migration is run inside a transaction. (с) doc. http://knexjs.org/#Migrations

P.s. i fix my problem. Knex 0.20.4 work incorrect with mysql, relocate to Postgre.

P.s.s. Hold dumps for version control - looks like indi practiсe or devOps case.

Comment: No you cannot rollback each transaction in Error case, with mysql (mysql does implicit commit some times preventing it). There is nothing knex specific in it. Knex uses just normal mysql transactions when running migrations on mysql, but they mostly doesn't work because people runs schema altering queries in them and you cannot rollback transaction in error case for DDL queries. Migrating to postgresql helps, because unlike mysql, postgresql does support also rolling back DDL queries. I'll add a bit more clarification to my answer about how mysql behaves.

Comment: Also you can generate/restore DB dumps also runtime, no need to store them in version control, but yeah a lot better to use postgresql instead if that was an option.