# Rolling back knex transaction using raw SQL expressions

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I have an array of raw SQL expressions I want to pass to knex.

```
const rawExpressions = ["CREATE TABLE new_table (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,email VARCHAR(50))","INSERT INTO new_table (firstname, lastname, email)VALUES (\"Test\", \"Name\", \"name@example.com\")", "INSERT INTO new_table (firstname, lastname, wrongfield) VALUES (\"Another\", \"Name\", \"test@example.com\")"]

knex.transaction(trx => {
  const queries: any[] = [];
  rawExpressions.forEach(async expression => {
    const query = knex.raw(expression).transacting(trx)
    queries.push(query)
  })

  Promise.all(queries)
    .then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback)
}).catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

This works if there's no error, but if there's an error (in the `rawExpressions` above there's a  `wrongfield`) I want it to not commit any part of the expressions and rollback. Instead it performs the first two expressions (creates table and inserts). 
Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: I think that it is related to the fact that DDL (Data Definition Language) can't be mixed with DML(Data Manipulation Language) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transactions-notes-on-ddl-and-normal-transaction.html

Comment: @felixmosh that was it! Make this the answer and I will accept - thanks

Comment: Also here are some more answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425666/knex-migration-fail-but-doesnt-revert-changes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179669/transaction-issue-with-knexjs-typescript-and-mariadb would be nice if SO had support for cross referencing questions without having to close them as duplicates....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to the fact that DDL (Data Definition Language) can't be mixed with DML(Data Manipulation Language) in transactions.

> DDL statements and operations with nontransactional engines do not "register" in thd->transaction lists, and thus do not modify the transaction state. Besides, each DDL statement in MySQL begins with an implicit normal transaction commit (a call to end_active_trans()), and thus leaves nothing to modify. However, as noted above for CREATE TABLE .. SELECT, some DDL statements can start a *new* transaction.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/transactions-notes-on-ddl-and-normal-transaction.html